# error with the mex command -g (no optimization)

Tags: matlab, mex, compiler-options

I am trying to mex a file in a script. The C file which has to be mexed is generated in one of the previous steps of the script before it is mexed.

When I use the below line in the script, everything works fine and the script runs successfully.

```
mex (strcat(component_name,'_s_func','.c'));
```

but when I add the same line below with

```
mex -g (strcat(component_name,'_s_func','.c'));
```

it gives me the error

> C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB~1\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: '(strcat(component_name,_s_func,.c))' not found.

Any idea why its not able to find the same file while using `-g` while it can find it when using without `-g` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your statement is that with the syntax

```
mex -g [...]
```

MATLAB assumes you are calling `mex` with the string arguments `'-g'` and `'[...]'` so it assumes that your file is called `(strcat(component_name,'_s_func','.c'))` and does not execute the command.

You can either use the solution you posted with `eval`, as that way you again call it with the strings `'-g'` and `'filename.c'`. Another possibility would be to use the syntax

```
mex('-g',strcat(component_name,'_s_func','.c'));
```

because that way the command `strcat` is really executed before calling `mex`.

--

This is the same behavior as e.g. with `clear`. As you might know, the following statements are equal:

```
clear a b c
clear('a','b','c');
```

Comment: Yes to the functional syntax.  Using eval is silly here.

Comment: but i still don't understand why not eval. why is your solution better than eval?? why both are not same . and thanks for this info. i accepted your answer already

Comment: @ArunKumar Because `mex` is itself a function, so you just have to call it like a function.  That is far easier to understand and less error prone then constructing a string to execute with `eval`.  Just my opinion.

Answer (score -2):

ok its possible to do this with eval command

```
file_name=(strcat(component_name,'_s_func','.c'));
eval(['mex -g ',file_name]);
```